# Merging Stack Over Flow Accounts

Tags: discussion, support

I am not sure If I am suppose to ask this question here, but I have been told by senior members of SO in C# room to ask it on meta.

My question is, I have got two accounts with different email addresses, I used both of them for Stock Over Flow and SharePoint Stack Over Flow and want to merge them.

e.g.

Account A, has  100 reputation on SO and 150 on SharePoint SO

[Account A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135136/timetothine)

Account B, has  300 reputation on SO and 250 on SharePoint SO

[Account B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090104/timetothine)

I was wondering how can I merge them together.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry my question was bit confusing i edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reputation points won't carry over from StackOverflow to SharePoint.SE.

That being said, it does look like you have duplicate accounts:

- SO account only: http://stackexchange.com/users/1453464/timetothine?tab=accounts
- SO, SharePoint, ServerFault, and Programmers accounts: http://stackexchange.com/users/1096639/timetothine?tab=accounts

You don't have duplicate SharePoint.SE accounts but we might be able to merge your StackOverflow accounts.

Can you try following the steps in this answer? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73801/146095

Comment: cheers
i tried the steps but non of them worked, so i might have to contact them through email i guess.